# Raspberry Pi 3 stretch mailutils segmentation fault

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have a problem when sending email from my Pi.
Recently I upgraded from jessie to stretch.
I want to send email with my Gmail account.

Installed ssmtp and mailutils.
sendmail can send emails.
But mail command always fails.
Mail -V also outputs segmentation fault.
I removed and purged mailutils but no change.

I catched core file and traced with gdb:

```
GNU gdb (Raspbian 7.7.1+dfsg-5+rpi1) 7.7.1  
Copyright (C) 2014 Free Software Foundation, Inc.  
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later  
<http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>  
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.  
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show 
copying" and "show warranty" for details.  
This GDB was configured as "arm-linux-gnueabihf".  
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.  
For bug reporting instructions, please see:  
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.  
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:  
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.  
For help, type "help".  
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...  
Reading symbols from mail...(no debugging symbols found)...done.  
warning: core file may not match specified executable file.  
[New LWP 1620]  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 9661, should be 2, 3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/80/04807a641723782e258f53fccb18b50d586940.debug]  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is -17502, should be 2, 3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/c3/90f5fdedf442d80621e7884a8b7661e9c8050f.debug]  
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]  
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libthread_db.so.1".  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is 30469, should be 2, 3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/44/d64b51763b6272bc47bd01723b6bdf68f38a1c.debug]  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is -25664, should be 2, 3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/09/4b30e8c4ded4dca627b8adf5e6324125084005.debug]  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is -27107, should be 2, 3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/81/ceb8fe32848c140c8a3d1741242c6a996bdb0d.debug]  
Dwarf Error: wrong version in compilation unit header (is -31079, should be 2, 3, or 4) [in module /usr/lib/debug/.build-id/e5/8601123ae22d2f43220005658f6cc8a9ad89f5.debug]  
Core was generated by `mail -V'.  
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.  
#0  0x76277654 in nettle_yarrow256_update ()  
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6  
(gdb)  
#0  0x76277654 in nettle_yarrow256_update ()  
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6  
(gdb) bt  
Cannot access memory at address 0x0  
#0  0x76277654 in nettle_yarrow256_update ()  
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6  
#1  0x7610bf6c in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls-deb0.so.28  
Cannot access memory at address 0x0  
Backtrace stopped: previous frame identical to this frame (corrupt stack?)  
(gdb) frame 0  
#0  0x76277654 in nettle_yarrow256_update ()  
   from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libnettle.so.6  
(gdb) frame 1  
#1  0x7610bf6c in ?? () from /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libgnutls-deb0.so.28  
(gdb)
```

```
:~ $ dpkg -l | grep mailutils  
ii  libmailutils5:armhf                   1:3.1.1-1                                   armhf        GNU Mail abstraction library  
ii  mailutils                             1:3.1.1-1                                   armhf        GNU mailutils utilities for handling mail  
ii  mailutils-common                      1:3.1.1-1                                 all          Common files for GNU mailutils
```

```
:~ $ dpkg -l | grep libnettle  
ii  libnettle4:armhf                      2.7.1-5+deb8u2                              armhf        low level cryptographic library (symmetric and one-way 
 cryptos)  
ii  libnettle6:armhf                      3.3-1+deb9u1                                armhf        low level cryptographic library (symmetric and one-way 
 cryptos)
```

```
: sudo apt-cache policy mailutils
mailutils:  
  installed version: 1:3.1.1-1  
  candidate:               1:3.1.1-1  
  version table:  
 *** 1:3.1.1-1 500  
        500 http://ftp.jaist.ac.jp/raspbian stretch/main armhf  Packages  
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

The latest mailutils version is 3.14.

Comment: Today I have gotten mailutils dependencies by "apt-get build-dep mailutils" and "apt-get source mailutils". configure and make and make install. On the make step I had to edit Makefile in order to match alocal version no and automake version no. Finally I had to export /usr/local/lib. Now mail -V command works expected.